# I have a specific line in while loop in VBA which doesn't execute but every other line executes

Tags: excel, while-loop, vba

Thank you in advance for going through this question. I am a newbie in Excel VBA world.

I have a spreadsheet which I am working on. This spreadsheet had some raw data with multiple columns and rows. I am trying to loop through the whole sheet and based on certain conditions (like the date falls in this week or item has a value Open), I am trying to copy the certain cells of a row to the other tab (sheet) of the spreadsheet.

So now, my while loop works okay and some cell values are getting copied to the next tab but just one cell value is not getting copied. When I try to debug it. I see the line is getting executed but the value is not getting copied. I double checked to see if I am referring to the correct column and it is correct. Please see the code below. I have `Sht1` and `Sht2` as public constants defined outside of `Sub` which is for sheet names "Tracking Sheet" and "ItemsDueSheet".

```
Public Const Sht1 = "Tracking Sheet"
Public Const Sht2 = "ItemsDueSheet"

Sub ItemsDueThisWeek()

Dim rwCounter As Integer
Dim rstart As Integer
Dim rEnd As Integer
Dim increment As Integer
rstart = 3
rEnd = 249
rwCounter = 5
increment = 1
While (rstart <= rEnd)
    'MsgBox (Format(Sheets(1).Cells(rStart, 16)))
    If (Format(Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 16), "ww-yyyy") = Format(Date, "ww-yyyy") And Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 15) <> "Closed - Done") Then
        Sheets(Sht2).Cells(rwCounter, 2) = increment
        Sheets(Sht2).Cells(rwCounter, 4) = Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 1)
        Sheets(Sht2).Cells(rwCounter, 5) = Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 2)
        **Sheets(Sht2).Cells(rwCounter, 8) = Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 7)**
        Sheets(Sht2).Cells(rwCounter, 3) = Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 13)
        Sheets(Sht2).Cells(rwCounter, 6) = Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 16)
        Sheets(Sht2).Cells(rwCounter, 7) = Sheets(Sht1).Cells(rstart, 12)

        rwCounter = rwCounter + 1
        increment = increment + 1
        'MsgBox ("A")

    Else

        'Sheets(2).Cells(rwcounter, 5) = Sheets(1).Cells(rStart, 1)
        'Sheets(2).Cells(rwcounter, 6) = Sheets(1).Cells(rStart, 2)
    End If

    rstart = rstart + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Here is the layout of ItemsdueSheet where I am trying to copy the cell based on button click from tracking sheet.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me. I see some cells where Product COde is blank...you sure there are values in the ones 'Due'? (I assume you highlited the one that isn't working with the **)

Comment: Judging by your data, it seems likely that column G is always blank on the rows where you have a due date that falls in the current week.  Is column G only populated on the rows that appear to be a "header" record for each "CAPA#"?

Answer (score 0):

@KacireeSoftware - So I am testing if the current date falls in this week and the column O Child status is not equal to Closed-Done then copy CAPA#, Child Task Number, Short Description, Due Date, Workstream member and Entity to the new sheet.
Your assumption is right. I have highlighted the code which is not working. 
Currently, how the spreadsheet is set up, wherever there is a product, there is no Child Due date and where there is child task there is no due date.

@YowE3K - Yes Column G is only populated for header record for each CAPA#.

Thank you @KacireeSoftware and @YowE3K  for your help. Your questions made me help find the problem.

The problem with the code was that it is currently testing if current date falls in this week and the column O Child status is not equal to Closed-Done then copy CAPA#, Child Task Number, Short Description, Due Date, Workstream member and Entity to the new sheet. However, the Product/Process Entity column is empty in the spreadsheet for those rows. So even though it executes it, it finds nothing to copy there and copies blank in those rows.

Thank you once again making me think in that direction. You guys are awesome.